# how to apply css on dynamic loaded html content (jquery mobile+backbone+phonegap)

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, dom, backbone.js, cordova

I have a system setup like the following

Phonegap
Backbone for routing
Jquery + jquerymobile for dom manipulation and UI

in the backbone view, I am dynamically loading a template from a file, and try to inject it into the html, but after page is loaded, no css is applied to the dynamically injected content. I tried everything from page() etc, nothing worked

here are my codes

view

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone',
        'text!services/main/template/Main.html'
        ], function($, _, backbone, tpl) {

    var el_selector = '#main_container';

    backbone.View.prototype.close = function() {
        alert('close for mainview');
        this.remove();
        this.unbind();
        if (this.onClose) {
            this.onClose();
        }
    };

    var MainView = backbone.View.extend({
        //always initialize el for which element to add the template to
        id : 'main_container', //jquery select
        initialize : function() {
            this.page_id = "#main_template_wrapper";
            this.holder ="#page_holder";
            this.status = 1;
            this.needUpdate = true;
        },
         // Event Handlers
        events: {
            //"click #example": "promptUser"
        },
        promptUser: function() {
            //prompt("Isn't this great?", "Yes, yes it is");
        },
        render : function() {
            alert('render main');
            try {
                var template = _.template(tpl);
                this.$el.html(template).page(); //append to the selector or perform other jquery dom manipulation option
                this.$el.attr('data-role','page');
                $(this.holder).html(this.$el.html());
                //$('body').append(this.$el.html());
                return this;
            } catch (error) {
                DEBUG(MSG_TYPE_ERROR,'render mainview error'+error.message,'MainView');
            }
        }
    });
    return (MainView);
});
```

router

```
//jquery changepage
        changePage: function (page, page_reverse, page_transition) {
            alert('change page called '+page.page_id);
            try {
page.render();
$.mobile.changePage($(this.currentView.el), {'reverse': reverse, 'changeHash': false, 'transition': mobile_transition});
            } catch (error) {
                DEBUG(MSG_TYPE_ERROR,' change page error in router >> '+error.message+' : '+error.stack,'AppRouter');
            }
        }
```

the html i try to inject

```
<div id="main_template_wrapper">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1>title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <a href='#userprofile' data-role="button">userprofile</a>
        <a href='#login' data-role="button">login</a>
        <a href='#tutorial/1/1' data-role="button">tutorial</a>
        <a href='./spec.html'>Jasming</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-id="fool" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="navbar">
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div>
```

inject into

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=false">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/library/phonegap/cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- Load jquery css files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/library/JQuery/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
    <!-- use require.js to load system -->
    <script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/library/require/require.js"></script>
    <!-- <script data-main="js/jm_requirejs_test.js" src="js/library/require/require.js"></script> -->
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body class="main_body">
<div id="page_holder">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help, I tried all possible combination of using page, even did $(document).page() this applied css, but alot of other things are broken.

Comment: This should be a CSS issue

Comment: Have you tried `$('pageID').trigger('pagecreate');` after injecting the items?

Comment: @Sushanth NO.this is a js issue.

Comment: CSS will always apply to what is on the page, your CSS file is probably not actually loaded.

Comment: Where do you load the custom css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.$el.html(template).page();
```

The above line in your code uses a deprecated method of jQM. Remove `page()` from this line. You don't need to do this anyway. You're just injecting it into DOM. `changePage` will take care of automatically initializing the styles of that page.

```
this.$el.attr('data-role','page');
```

Remove this line and add `data-role=page` in your template, like this :

```
<div id="main_template_wrapper" data-role="page">
```

Next, look at this line :

```
$(this.holder).html(this.$el.html());
```

In this line, `this.$el` would do. Remove the call to `html()`.

```
$.mobile.changePage($(this.currentView.el),..
```

In the above line, `$(this.currentView.el)` can be made into an `id` of the page. `changePage` works best with an ID.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks remove .html from this.$el is a great tips, and I was also forced to not have data-role='page' and append it directly to body, after these it worked.

Comment: Good. Please mark this as the answer of you think this has helped you.